# Pure CSS3 slider with buttons and autorotation

Tags: css, slider, autorotate

I want to make a pure CSS3 (no JS) slider with side buttons for rotation and also it have auto rotate. I founded example http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/ but it does note auto rotate. What I need to change in this example? Or maby somebody can advice another solution?

Comment: Put them inside `@keyframes` changing the margin at the desired `%`.